# Whats the best way to pupulate data from sqlite to listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

I am new with android programing,I hope you can Help me
I have some questions at first,
I want to populate data from an Sqlite database but I don't know whats the best way to do it..My database some times have lots of data and I want the an optimizes way for get data from it.I  searched alot and find that SimpleCursorAdapter is good for my purpose,But I couldn't find any way to make it work.. this is my code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_read_book);
    ListView Peot_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_poet_name);
    String SDcardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    String DbPath = SDcardPath + "/Tosca/" + "persian_poem.db";




    try {
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DbPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);

        // here you do something with your database ...
        getData();

    db.close();

    }
    catch (SQLiteException e) {

    }

}



private void getData() {
    TextView txtMsg;

    txtMsg=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtmsg);
        try {

        // obtain a list  from DB
            String TABLE_NAME = "classicpoems__poet_contents";
            String COLUMN_ID = "poet_id";
            String COLUMN_NAME = "poet_name";
            String COLUMN_CENTURY = "century_start";
            String [] columns ={COLUMN_ID,COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_CENTURY};

        Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns,null, null, null, null, COLUMN_ID);
        int theTotal = c.getCount();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Total: " + theTotal, 1).show();

        int idCol = c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID);
        int nameCol = c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME);
        int centuryCol = c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CENTURY);


        while (c.moveToNext()) {
        columns[0] = Integer.toString((c.getInt(idCol)));
        columns[1] = c.getString(nameCol);
        columns[2] = c.getString(centuryCol);


        txtMsg.append( columns[0] + " " + columns[1] + " "
        + columns[2] + "\n" );
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), 1).show();
        }




}
```

Now I Can read what I want from Database and they show in txtMsg but I want to show them to a list view..I cant define SimpleCursorAdapter at all and always get error or an empty list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After:

```
Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns,null, null, null, null, COLUMN_ID);
```

Simply create a CursorAdapter, like [SimpleCursorAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html), with this Cursor, then pass the Adapter to your ListView. Something like:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, c, 
            new String[] {COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_CENTURY}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}, 0);
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

(You don't really need any of the other code below `Cursor c = db.query(...);`.)

---

How each row looks depends on the layout that you use in the Adapter, in this case `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2`. If you want to customize how the information is displayed then write your own layout.

Comment: Thanks for your help,But when I add your code I got error "column _id does not exist" but when I remove this part every thing works fine.... //SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, c, 
      //        new String[] {COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_CENTURY}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}, 0);
   
  //ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_poet_name);
  //list.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Does your table have an `integer primary key`, perhaps `"poet_id"`? Android requires Cursors have a key with the name `_id` to work with Adapters.

Comment: A quick solution might be to use an alias `String COLUMN_ID = "poet_id as _id";` or a more permanent is to incorporate `_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` into your table schema.

Comment: Thanks for your information but now I added an column named _id with primary key but I get that error yet..Its column name must be _id right?

Comment: Yes, the column must be `_id`. Did you change your columns in the Cursor? Something like: `String [] columns ={"_id",COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_CENTURY};`

Comment: Thanks My friend I finally could load it to correctly,But I get this error too  `03-24 22:23:47.127: E/CursorWindow(17496): Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 2 rows, 4 columns'`
My table must has al least 2 rows?I dont get its mean

Comment: The import information is `row 0, column -1` that means you are trying to read a column that doesn't exist. It looks like you are still using `int idCol = c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID);` and `columns[0] = Integer.toString((c.getInt(idCol)));` but `COLUMN_ID` is no longer in your query.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to delete those extra lines..Thanks again for your time and great helps